# How to write sql query in an executeQuery method?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have an account_holder table with a field userId and I have a data set as data.I want to select only that record from account_holder which having userId as `data[3]` i.e (4 field of data set). I am writing query as:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from account_holder where userID = 'data[3]' ");
```

But my rs is `null` the entry not gets in to the ResultSet  object rs. Plz tell me the correct way to write sql query with where clause inside the executeQuery() method.

Comment: `rs` cannot be `null` unless the JDBC driver you're using is buggy. `executeQuery` will either return a non-null `ResultSet` **or** it will throw a `SQLException`. Also, you are currently comparing `userID` against a string literal with value `'data[3]'` which will likely produce an **empty** result set. Is `data` an array in your Java application or something in your MySQL database?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  data is an array of strings .. I am reading a input file and putting the contents of file in to this data array and then comparing the userID field which is of type **varchar(40)** against the **data[3](string type)** to check whether this user is already created in the account_holder table or not.I am using this to check whether rs is empty or not.  **if(rs!=null&&rs.next())** { **non empty which means user is already created** }

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't put pertinent information in the comments. In any case, you need to read up on [prepared statements and parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1):

As the first post said this is one way of handling this:

```
     try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); // Creating Statement

        // Executing Statement
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM account_holder WHERE userID = '" + data[3] + "'");

        // Check if result set has entries
        if (resultSet.first()) // If so the user already exists
            System.out.println("User already exists! " + resultSet.getString("userID"));
        else // If not the user does not exist
            System.out.println("User does not exist!");

        // Clean up
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But in your context I would actually recommend using a `PreparedStatement`:

```
    try {
        // Making statement
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM account_holder WHERE userID = ?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, data[3]); // Set String for the first question mark in Query

        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); // Executing the Prepared Statement

        // Check if result set has entries
        if (resultSet.first()) // If so the user already exists
            System.out.println("User already exists! " + resultSet.getString("userID"));
        else // If not the user does not exist
            System.out.println("User does not exist!");

        // Clean up
        resultSet.close();
        preparedStatement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to only change the query in the executeQuery method

example:

```java
Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from account_holder where userID = '"+data[3]+"' ");
```

or you can also run the following command:

```java
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from account_holder where userID = "+data[3]+"");
```

Comment: Although this might solve the immediate problem, this solution is vulnerable to SQL injection. It would be better to use a prepared statement with parameters.